# Pytorch : Applying lambda transformations in case of segmentation tasks in custom transformation function

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, transformation, image-segmentation

I am trying to perform multiclass image segmentation. There are some transformations which should be applied to both image and masks like rotations and flips etc. I followed [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torchvision-transfors-how-to-perform-identical-transform-on-both-image-and-target/10606/7?u=rishav_sapahia)
post and applied it but the issue is I have certain lambda transformations also which I need to apply but I can't apply using the above method.How to apply them.
Below are the transformations I need-

```
data_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomCrop((512,512)),
                             transforms.Lambda(gaussian_blur),
                             transforms.Lambda(elastic_transform),
                             transforms.RandomRotation([+90,+180]),
                             transforms.RandomRotation([+180,+270]),
                             transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                             transforms.ToTensor(),
                             transforms.Normalize(mean=train_mean, std=train_std)
                           ])
```

My Dataloader for identical transformations for the image and mask is below, I wasn't able to apply my lambda transformations in it, it was throwing an error 
`AttributeError: module 'torchvision.transforms.functional' has no attribute 'Lambda'`

```
class DataLoaderSegmentation(data.Dataset):
def __init__(self,folder_path,transform = None):
    super(DataLoaderSegmentation, self).__init__()
    self.img_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'images','*.tif'))
    self.mask_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'mask','*.bmp'))
    # self.transform = transform


def mask_to_class(self,mask):
    target = torch.from_numpy(mask)
    h,w = target.shape[0],target.shape[1]
    masks = torch.empty(h, w, dtype=torch.long)
    colors = torch.unique(target.view(-1,target.size(2)),dim=0).numpy()
    target = target.permute(2, 0, 1).contiguous()
    mapping = {tuple(c): t for c, t in zip(colors.tolist(), range(len(colors)))}
    for k in mapping:
        idx = (target==torch.tensor(k, dtype=torch.uint8).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2))
        validx = (idx.sum(0) == 3) 
        masks[validx] = torch.tensor(mapping[k], dtype=torch.long)
    return masks

def transform(self,image,mask):
    i, j, h, w = transforms.RandomCrop.get_params(
    image, output_size=(512, 512))
    image = TF.crop(image, i, j, h, w)
    mask = TF.crop(mask, i, j, h, w)

    #image = TF.Lambda(gaussian_blur),

    #image = TF.Lambda(elastic_transform)
    # Random horizontal flipping
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        image = TF.hflip(image)
        mask = TF.hflip(mask)

    image = TF.rotate(image,90)
    mask = TF.rotate(mask,90)
    image = TF.rotate(image,180)
    mask = TF.rotate(mask,180)
    image = TF.rotate(image,270)
    mask = TF.rotate(mask,270)

    # Transform to tensor
    image = TF.to_tensor(image)
    return image, mask

def __getitem__(self, index):
    img_path = self.img_files[index]
    mask_path = self.mask_files[index]
    data = Image.open(img_path)
    label = Image.open(mask_path)
    data,label = self.transform(data,label)
    label = np.array(label)  
    mask = self.mask_to_class(label)
    return data,mask


def __len__(self):
    return len(self.img_files)
```

How to do it, or is there any other way to do it?

Edit---
Following is my solution for it-

```
class DataLoaderSegmentation(data.Dataset):
def __init__(self,folder_path,transform = None):
    super(DataLoaderSegmentation, self).__init__()
    self.img_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'images','*.tif'))
    self.mask_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,'mask','*.bmp'))
    self.transforms = transform
    #for img_path in img_files:
     #   self.mask_files.append(os.path.join(folder_path,'masks',os.path.basename(img_path))

def mask_to_class(self,mask):
    target = torch.from_numpy(mask)
    h,w = target.shape[0],target.shape[1]
    masks = torch.empty(h, w, dtype=torch.long)
    colors = torch.unique(target.view(-1,target.size(2)),dim=0).numpy()
    target = target.permute(2, 0, 1).contiguous()
    mapping = {tuple(c): t for c, t in zip(colors.tolist(), range(len(colors)))}
    for k in mapping:
        idx = (target==torch.tensor(k, dtype=torch.uint8).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2))
        validx = (idx.sum(0) == 3) 
        masks[validx] = torch.tensor(mapping[k], dtype=torch.long)
    return masks

def transform(self,image,mask):
    i, j, h, w = transforms.RandomCrop.get_params(
    image, output_size=(512, 512))
    image = TF.crop(image, i, j, h, w)
    mask = TF.crop(mask, i, j, h, w)

    #image = TF.Lambda(gaussian_blur),
   # mask = 
    #image = TF.Lambda(elastic_transform)
    # Random horizontal flipping
    image = F.Lambda(gaussian_blur)
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        image = TF.hflip(image)
        mask = TF.hflip(mask)

    image = TF.rotate(image,90)
    mask = TF.rotate(mask,90)
    image = TF.rotate(image,180)
    mask = TF.rotate(mask,180)
    image = TF.rotate(image,270)
    mask = TF.rotate(mask,270)

    # Transform to tensor
    #image = TF.to_tensor(image)
    #mask = TF.to_tensor(mask)
    return image, mask

def __getitem__(self, index):
    img_path = self.img_files[index]
    mask_path = self.mask_files[index]
    data = Image.open(img_path)
    label = Image.open(mask_path)
   # label = np.array(label)
    data,label = self.transform(data,label)
    label = np.array(label)
    data = np.array(data)
    #label = np.transpose(label,(2,0,1))
    mask = self.mask_to_class(label)
    if transforms is not None:
        data = self.transforms(data)
    return data,mask
   # return data, torch.from_numpy(label).long()

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.img_files)
```

and the transformation are below-

```
data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
                             transforms.Lambda(gaussian_blur),
                             transforms.Lambda(elastic_transform),
                             transforms.ToTensor(),
                             transforms.Normalize(mean=train_mean, std=train_std)
                           ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the class was moved from `torchvision.transforms.functional` to [`torchvision.transforms.transforms`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/3483342733673c3182bd5f8a4de3723a74ce5845/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py#L301). I think you can probably just import it directly from [`torchvision.transforms`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/3483342733673c3182bd5f8a4de3723a74ce5845/torchvision/transforms/__init__.py)

Comment: No, actually I don't know how to use torchvision.transforms in my custom transform function but I did a hack, don't know whether it's a right way or not. I used the transformations which I need on both image and mask in the function inside class rest of the transformation I applied using `torchvision.transforms `  in the normal way . I am obtaining the same output but I am not sure though is it the right way or not

Comment: I'm a bit confused: your question posted about an `AttributeError`: did my suggestion resolve that issue? Or was that not the issue to begin with? It sounds like my response resolved your problem and you now have a separate new question, which should probably be a separate post from this one. If my response resolved your `AttributeError`, you should accept the answer and post a new question.

Comment: I used your method but it gave me this error `TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'torchvision.transforms.transforms.Lambda'>` so I used another approach which I edited below the edit section, it solved my problem, though I should have posted it in the solution but I refrained and then I asked your opinion on my solution .